# Ordering of Jmeter Thread Groups

Tags: jmeter

I have a setup like this,

Test Plan =>Execute Threads in Parallel

```
-THread Group 1
-THread Group 2
-THread Group 3
-THread Group 4
-THread Group 5
```

I want 1,2 and 5 to execute in parallel. 3 has to start after 1 finishes and 4 has to start after 2 has finished. How can I create such inter dependency in the execution order?

Answer (score 1):

Use Transaction controller or simple controller to execute one after the other.

Implement the logic in the Thread Groups in Simple Controllers. Let's name them SimpleController 1 ... SimpleController 5.

In the TestPlan choose parallel execution of thread groups. Create three Thread Groups A, B and C.

Thread Group A has Simple Controller 1 and 3
Thread Group B has Simple Controller 2 and 4
Thread Group C has Simple Controller 5

The above arrangement would achieve your dependency requirements.